# Topic detection for a sentence or an article using Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining, natural-language, topic-models

Besides LDA (Latent Dirichlet allocation), are there other ways or methods to detect a topic or category from a sentence?

For example, all the categories or tags from news websites can be used to train a classifier to predict the topic for a new sentence or article or a paragraph.

Are there any known public datasets with keywords to topics relationship which can be used a training set in a classic classification problem?

A simple training data example of a news website:

```
Article 1: category x 
Article 2: category x 
Article 3: category x
Article 4: category y 
Article 5: category y 
Article 6: category y
```

It's a very simple example but it's enough to paint the picture. Now use this data to predict the category of a new article.

A bit of explanation: 
By topic I mean if a text is talking about politics, entertainment, business, finance, lifestyle etc and ideally, a classification into sub-categories of such types. A similar categorization is used in the news website where they place each article in a specific category.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about a text classification problem. There are lots of data sets for this.

1. 20 newsgroups data http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/
2. Yahoo answers data https://github.com/juanshishido/text-classification
3. DBPedia ontology dataset (can't find a link right now)

There is also something called supervised LDA that might interest you.

Comment: 1 and 2 are relevant but too small for my use case.

Comment: You could do hashtag prediction on Twitter

Answer (score 1):

I really liked Gensim package for Python. There they use a collection of articles from wikipedia as training, you can find it [here](http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) (8GB).

As transformations they use:

1. Term Frequency * Inverse Document Frequency, Tf-Idf
2. Latent Semantic Indexing, LSI (or sometimes LSA)
3. Random Projections, RP

and then LDA and its transformation HDP. You can find a good tutorial [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html).